# one label and 3 checkboxes in C# language

Tags: c#

Got a problem with my project, I've one label and 3 checkboxes. What I want is if I unchecked one of checkboxes one label text is cleared. The problem of my code is if I uncheck one of the checkboxes, all labels text is cleared.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
    if(checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        string lb1 = label1.Text + c.Text + "@";
        lb1 = lb1.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
        label1.Text = lb1;
    }
    else 
    { 
        label1.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question. But in your code is written exactly what you describes: if checkBox1 is unchecked -> label text is empty

Comment: What I want is if I unchecked one of the checked box, only that unchecked box proprieties is remove not all text. I have 3 checkbox that have 1 text message each. The output go thru to the label1.Text

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should assign `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` event handler to each `CheckedChanged` event of your checkboxes. If I understand your problem, the code should be as following:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = (label1.Tag as string);
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        label1.Text += checkBox1.Text;
    }
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        label1.Text += checkBox2.Text;
    }
    if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        label1.Text += checkBox3.Text;
    }
    label1 += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

`label1.Tag` stores the initial value of your `label1.Text`. It should be assigned somewhere in `Load` event of your main window:

```
label1.Tag = label.Text;
```

Comment: Sorry for that. But I've got the same output. What I want is if I unchecked one of the checked box, only that unchecked box proprieties is remove not all text. I have 3 checkbox that have 1 text message each. The output go thru to the label1.Text.

Comment: @navabvillordon Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
    if(checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        string lb1 = label1.Text + c.Text + "@";
        lb1 = lb1.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
        label1.Text = lb1;
    }
    else 
    {
        string str = c.Text + "@";
        str = str.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
        label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace(str, "");
    }
```